# c# finding objects that are children of other objects

Tags: c#, oop

I am (starting) programming in Revit. To simplify my problem I have this example.

I have an drawing that is build like OOP. The objects in the drawing are C# objects. In this drawing I have a house that has rooms, in the rooms are other objects and so on. All these different objects can be nested very deep. Some of these objects for example contain screws. To find all the screws in the house I have to search all the object hierarchies. But how can I know that I have found all the screws and it takes a long time.

If I have a say in it, every time I created a screw, I put it in a custom collection. But I can't control that process. When I get the drawing it could be drawn already.

So my question is: Is there a way to create a collection of screws based on the fact that they are (a type) screws?

And if not, is this a flaw in OOP or is there a good reason (safety) for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem with OOP but more likely with the implementation that must meet the requirement to model a house in great detail and list all of its component parts. Let's look at a fairly naïve implementation where each part of the house has a parent, and has a collection of children, as well as a method that recurses the children looking for parts of a particular type:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        House h = new House();
        Console.WriteLine("This house has {0} screws", h.FindAll<Screw>().Count());
    }

    public interface IHouseComponent
    {
        IHouseComponent Parent { get; }
        IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>() where T : IHouseComponent;
        IEnumerable<IHouseComponent> Children { get; }
    }

    public abstract class HouseComponentBase : IHouseComponent
    {
        private List<IHouseComponent> _children = new List<IHouseComponent>();
        protected HouseComponentBase(IHouseComponent parent)
        {
            Parent = parent;
        }

        protected void AddChild(IHouseComponent component)
        {
            _children.Add(component);
        }

        public IHouseComponent Parent { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerable<IHouseComponent> Children { get { return _children; } }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>() where T : IHouseComponent
        {
            var list = new List<T>();
            list.AddRange(_children.OfType<T>()); // add appropriate components in direct children
            foreach (var node in _children)
                list.AddRange(node.FindAll<T>()); // then add all components that are part of descendants               

            return list;
        }
    }

    public class House : HouseComponentBase
    {
        public House()
            : base(null)
        {
            // two room house
            AddChild(new Room(this));
            AddChild(new Room(this));
        }
    }

    public class Room : HouseComponentBase
    {
        public Room(House parent)
            : base(parent)
        {
            // 4 walls per room - no ceiling or floor
            AddChild(new Wall(this));
            AddChild(new Wall(this));
            AddChild(new Wall(this));
            AddChild(new Wall(this));
        }
    }

    public class Wall : HouseComponentBase
    {
        public Wall(Room parent)
            : base(parent)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
                AddChild(new Screw(this));// each wall has 64 screws
        }
    }

    public class Screw : HouseComponentBase
    {
        public Screw(IHouseComponent parent) // a screw can be part of any component
            : base(parent)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

For a simple model of a house this would work but as your scale you model to more and more detail (adding floors, ceilings, sheetrock, studs, furniture etc) it will not scale well as everything is kept in memory at all times. If you were trying to model a complex CAD darawing of an actual house and determine a Bill of Materials for instance this simple implementation would likely overwhelm any machine. You'd want to figure out how to store application state and retrieve application state in such a way that it didn't need to be in RAM at all times but still allowed it to be queried and inspected with consuming code being none the wiser. That's the true power of OOP.

So if you replaced the in memory collections and the `FindAll` method implementations with methods that queried a Sql Database or CAD file for instance the basic class design (the OOP part) still largely could remain intact. OOP is all about how you structure your types to best model your problem domain and organize the implementation. I can promise you that a system like AutoCAD, which can in fact turn the design of a house into a bill of materials relies heavily on OOP.

Comment: Thanks for you elaborated answer. Saving this info in a database is a good suggestion. From a CAD program designer point of view I understand the structure they use to build the drawing. And they provide filters for bigger objects such as Walls. But I want to create simulations with the "screws" and this data is hidden in plain sight. :). The problem is I can't never be sure I have all the Screws and I can't test for all possiblities.